# How to use queryExpr for dijit/form/ComboBox

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have Combobox `dijit/form/ComboBox` and I want that when a user starts typing the combo box shows result that contains letter.

For Example combox have this value

- Nebraska
- South Dakota
- Delaware

when users type "D"
the result should be

- South Dakota
- Delaware

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple just user the  `queryExpr: "*${0}*"` to search if the combo select item contains the search keyword .

bellow a complete sample using this last :

```js
require([
    "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"
], function(Memory, ComboBox){
    var stateStore = new Memory({
        data: [
            {name:"", id:""},
            {name:"Nebraska", id:"NE"},
            {name:"South Dakota", id:"SD"},
            {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"},
            {name:"Test1", id:"T1"},
            {name:"Test2", id:"T2"},
            {name:"Test3", id:"T3"}
        ]
    });

    var ComboBox = new ComboBox({
        id: "filteringCombo",
        store: stateStore,
        queryExpr: "*${0}*",
        searchAttr: "name"
    }, "filterCombo").startup();
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true}
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="claro">
  <div id="filterCombo"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey @mostafa Does this help :) ??

Comment: +1 :) , If this helped you , please mark the answer as resolved ✓ (left the answer ) ( like in this image => [image resolve post](http://i.stack.imgur.com/T8umg.png) ) thank you :)

Comment: I do it before you tell me, again Thanks.